# SQL Server checking inventory stock on insert

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I'm creating an inventory for a restaurant using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

This is [diagram from 5 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukBeE.png)

I want to write a trigger for whenever I insert new order into `orderDetail` table, the table from inventory will auto update the `outStock` as `orderDetail.quantity` and the `stockLeft` based on previous `stockLeft` within the table that matched the `product_ID`.

I'm very new to SQL Server. Any opinion/suggestion would be very helpful to me. Thanks!!

Here are my table database from

[inventory and orderDetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tFbM.png)

This is what I've tried so far

```
    USE [BuffaloWildWingsDB]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER update_stock
ON orderDetail
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stock INT,@productID INT, @prevDate date, @prevStock INT;
    SET @stock = (SELECT quantity FROM orderDetail)
    SET @productID = (SELECT product_ID FROM orderDetail)
    SET @prevDate = (SELECT [date] FROM inventory WHERE inventory.product_ID = @productID AND [date] < GETDATE())
    SET @prevStock = (SELECT stockLeft FROM inventory WHERE [date] = @prevDate)
    INSERT INTO inventory (product_ID, outStock, stockLeft) VALUES (@productID,@stock,@prevStock-@stock);
END
```

I can run this query fine but whenever I update `orderDetail` with

```
INSERT INTO orderDetail(order_ID,product_ID, quantity) values (10101, 1013, 2)
GO
```

I got this error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_stock, Line 14 Subquery
> returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
> follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
> expression. The statement has been terminated.

Any idea?

Comment: I updated the question. I don't know how to make a FUNCTION to check for value of the same product_ID in previous date. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger will only work for separate inserts only. If you will insert several rows at once it will fail. Also you are selecting from base table instead of `INSERTED` table. Here is what your trigger should look like:

```
insert into inventory (product_id, outStock, stockLeft)
select i.product_id, i.quantity, isnull(oa.stockLeft, 0) - i.quantity
from inserted i
outer apply(select top 1 stockLeft 
            from inventory 
            where product_id = i.product_id and [date] < GETDATE()
            order by [date] desc)oa
```

Comment: @DucTruong, why not to accept the answer if it answers your question?